# Can't configure frame relay T1 on Cisco 1760

Tags: cisco, t1

I am trying to configure a data T1 via a Frame Relay.

The ISP provided me the following information:

```
1. IP address
2. Gateway address
3. Encapsulation Frame Relay
4. DLCI 100
5. BZ8 ESF (I think the bz8 was supposed to be b8zs)
6. Time Slot (1 al 24).
```

And what I have configured up until now is the following:

```
interface Serial0/0
  ip address <ip address> 255.255.255.252
  encapsulation frame-relay
  service-module t1 timeslots 1-24
  frame-relay interface-dlci 100
```

**sh service-module s0/0** (outputs):

```
Module type is T1/fractional
    Hardware revision is 0.128, Software revision is 0.2,
    Image checksum is 0x73D70058, Protocol revision is 0.1
Receiver has no alarms.
Framing is **ESF**, Line Code is **B8ZS**, Current clock source is line,
Fraction has **24 timeslots** (64 Kbits/sec each), Net bandwidth is 1536 Kbits/sec.
Last module self-test (done at startup): Passed
Last clearing of alarm counters 00:17:17
    loss of signal        :    0,
    loss of frame         :    0,
    AIS alarm             :    0,
    Remote alarm          :    2, last occurred 00:10:10
    Module access errors  :    0,
Total Data (last 1 15 minute intervals):
    0 Line Code Violations, 0 Path Code Violations
    0 Slip Secs, 0 Fr Loss Secs, 0 Line Err Secs, 0 Degraded Mins
    0 Errored Secs, 0 Bursty Err Secs, 0 Severely Err Secs, 0 Unavail Secs
Data in current interval (138 seconds elapsed):
    0 Line Code Violations, 0 Path Code Violations
    0 Slip Secs, 0 Fr Loss Secs, 0 Line Err Secs, 0 Degraded Mins
    0 Errored Secs, 0 Bursty Err Secs, 0 Severely Err Secs, 0 Unavail Secs
```

sh int:

```
FastEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is PQUICC_FEC, address is 000d.6516.e5aa (bia 000d.6516.e5aa)
  Internet address is 10.0.0.1/24
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 100BaseTX/FX
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:20:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes
     Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     191 packets output, 20676 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out

Serial0/0 is up, line protocol is down
  Hardware is PQUICC with Fractional T1 CSU/DSU
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1536 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation FRAME-RELAY, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  LMI enq sent  157, LMI stat recvd 0, LMI upd recvd 0, DTE LMI down
  LMI enq recvd 23, LMI stat sent  0, LMI upd sent  0
  LMI DLCI 1023  LMI type is CISCO  frame relay DTE
  FR SVC disabled, LAPF state down
  Broadcast queue 0/64, broadcasts sent/dropped 2/0, interface broadcasts 0
  Last input 00:24:51, output 00:00:05, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 00:27:20
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: weighted fair
  Output queue: 0/1000/64/0 (size/max total/threshold/drops)
     Conversations  0/1/256 (active/max active/max total)
     Reserved Conversations 0/0 (allocated/max allocated)
     Available Bandwidth 1152 kilobits/sec
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     23 packets input, 302 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     1725 input errors, 595 CRC, 1099 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 30 abort
     246 packets output, 3974 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 48 interface resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     4 carrier transitions
     DCD=up  DSR=up  DTR=up  RTS=up  CTS=up

Serial0/0.1 is down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is PQUICC with Fractional T1 CSU/DSU
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1536 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation FRAME-RELAY
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
Serial0/0.100 is down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is PQUICC with Fractional T1 CSU/DSU
  Internet address is <ip address>/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1536 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation FRAME-RELAY
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
```

And everything seems to be accounted for to me, but apparently I'm missing something.

My issue is that I'm stuck on interface up, line protocol down, so the T1 doesn't go up.

Comment: Well what's the problem exactly? You haven't stated what kind of trouble you're having. Also, can you post the output of "sh int"?

Comment: you should map the ip of the remote gateway in that p2p to the dlci as well :) such as frame-relay map ip 192.168.0.1 100

Comment: Hi @ItsGC the frame relay map command is giving me the following error **FRAME-RELAY INTERFACE-DLCI command should be used on point-to-point interfaces**. I'm specifying the command like so: frame-relay map ip <ISP gateway/remote IP> 100. And I'm specifying it on the subinterface that has the frame-relay interface-dlci 100 configured. Is this correct?

Comment: Well it seems you have L1 and L2 issues so my L3 comment is hardly relevant at the moment :)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the configuration - specifically the configuration of s0/0 and s0/0.1.

Comment: You have a yellow alarm, the problem is on the far end. Make sure the ISP has actually enabled your port on their end. Make sure the telco has released the line.

Answer (score 5):

You're showing a remote alarm, for that you may find [Cisco's troubleshooting guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk713/tk628/technologies_tech_note09186a00801069ff.shtml#topic4) useful.

Assuming the hardware is good...

I'd check the cabling between your router and the demarc, make sure it's plugged in, not damaged, not a bad cable, etc. Then I'd call the ISP and ask them why it isn't working. Last time I had this happen, it was because AT&T had screwed up and gave me the wrong DLCI, which took a six hour conference call to figure out...

---

From your update, I see:

```
     1725 input errors, 595 CRC, 1099 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 30 abort
```

Someone more experienced may have better ideas, but this definitely makes me think you have an issue with your cabling, or a noisy line, or the telco clock is completely wrong. It's probably time for that conference call.

Comment: Hi @Michael I tried the hardware loopback, and it didn't generate any remote alarms. So I guess the hardware is OK. Although is not like I could ping it. I mean the line protocol never did come up. I trying my luck to see if there's a mistake on the DLCI's. Thank you.

Comment: I know, your right. It sucks because I really wanted to finish this today.

Comment: The ISP had setup the wrong DLCI. We are up and runnign now. To anyone else having a similar issue take a look at this guide by Cisco it was invaluable.
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/internetworking/troubleshooting/guide/tr1918.html#wp1020680